# Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Tags: php, boolean

i'm new in php coding, and a have a small problem.
I wanna make more pages to be posted if there are more than 20 rows in a table.
What is the problem exactly?

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT COUNT ID FROM out_fact"; 
$query = mysql_query($sql); 
$result = mysql_fetch_row($query); 
$total_records = $result[0]; 
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / 20); 

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
            echo "<a href='view.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> "; 
}; 
?>
```

If you need all the code, let me know. Thanks a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate of ["mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given" in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-selec)

Comment: You're not bothering to check the success or otherwise of function calls that aren't garantueed to succeed.  That's sloppy.  For example you're not checking that mysql_query returned a resultset or False.  If it returns False then the previous query failed.  Also you shouldn't be using mysql_* because it's deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Query syntax should be,

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM out_fact
```

**Waring:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Thank you so much, i'll give it a try to PDO, but i have to startover. I can't upvote since i don't have required reputation, otherwise i would'v. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

`count()` is a function you are using count like a constant try

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM out_fact";
```

For more :- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/counting-rows.html